# How does glfw handle input in terms of implementation?

Tags: opengl, glfw

GLFW is clearly an OpenGL framework, which means we are aming to work with graphics card initially. How input gets handled then? According to the docs, the input and window are just two main purpuses and that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean "How could I handle inputs with GLFW?" Or "How does GLFW do to handle stuff like keyboards events and transmit that to the user?"

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt yes, How does GLFW do to handle stuff like keyboards events and transmit that to the user?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, GLFW is not a *OpenGL framework* but a *OpenGL applications framework*. It's basically a set of libraries and source files which facilitate you the task of build applications. This layer of abstraction allows you to write multi-platform applications without knowing *anything* of the Operative System API; you don't need to know how *Linux* manages keyboard events, just learn how *GLFW*.

To respond your question, keyboard, mouse, window... events are probably processed by the CPU, on the function call `glfwPollEvents()`. Callbacks may be added with the `glfwSetKeyCallback` function, as stated [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_key_input). GLFW will maintain a *list* of functions (callbacks) to execute when the OS triggers an event.

To simplify the answer, GLFW will manage the following modules of your application (OS independent):

- **OpenGL**: OpenGL API management. Mostly processed by the GPU.
- **Window**: System window management (resize, resolution, etc). Processed by the GPU (rendering) and CPU (processing).
- **Events**: Events fired by the Operative System (keyboard events, mouse events, window events...). Mostly processed by the CPU.